Are the natural powers of two conservatively embedded in $\mathbb{C}$?
This is a followup to this question.
Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a structure - in the sense of first-order logic - with the graphs of addition and multiplication. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the substructure with underlying set $\{2^n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Question: is there a relation on $\mathcal{X}$ which is definable in $\mathbb{C}$ together with a predicate for $\mathcal{X}$, but which is not definable in $\mathcal{X}$ itself?

Here "definable" is with respect to first-order logic. The motivation for this question is the following: if we replace $\mathcal{X}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ we get a negative answer, but this relies on the expressive power of $\mathbb{Z}$ - specifically, the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ interprets an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and infinite transcendence degree together with a predicate naming the integers. By contrast, considered on its own $\mathcal{X}$ "is" just a copy of $(\mathbb{N};+)$, and so the previous argument breaks down immediately.

I admit I'm a little confused about what signature we're talking about: $\mathbb{C}$ with only the relations of $+$ and $\times$ and equality?

@cody Yes, that's correct.

Minor note which you may already know, van den Dries showed in this paper that the theory of $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,{2^n : n \in \mathbb{N}})$ is decidable. This interprets the structure you're talking about (and is probably biinterpretable with it), so $\mathbb{Z}$ is not definable in the structure in this question.

@JamesEHanson Ooh, I didn't know that - that's neat (although I don't think it immediately helps here)!

The paper shows more than just "it's decidable" - it uses quantifier elimination, and I think a corollary of the QE result is that the definable subsets of $\mathcal{X}$ are exactly the subsets definable in $\mathcal{X}$. If I'm right, that gives an answer to this question as well, because anything definable in the structure in the question would also be definable in this structure that interprets it.

@JamesEHanson Why do you say it's probably bi-interpretable with it? $\mathbb{R}$ has an ordering after all ...

@pastebee The quantifier elimination that occurs is in an expanded language, where the additional definitions do use quantifiers. So I don't think it quite gets what we want here.

@NoahSchweber Oh, you're right. I was forgetting that automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are going to fix the set of powers of $2$.

$\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbf Z}$I'm a bit confused: the natural powers of $2$ are not a substructure of the field of complex numbers (they are not closed under addition). So I guess you mean that you consider them as a substructure of the multiplication monoid? When we just forget about addition, then $(\mathbf C,\cdot)$ is (I think) isomorphic to ${\mathbf Q}^{\oplus \mathfrak c}\oplus(\mathbf Q/\bZ)\cup {0}$, with $X$ being isomorphic to $\mathbf N$ embedded in one of the $\mathbf Q$-s.

(cont.) Then stable embeddedness should be resolved by q.e. in abelian groups, I think. But I guess you don't mean to only look at the multiplication monoid, but rather, a multiplication-substructure as compared to the induced structure from the field.

@tomasz That's incorrect. As I said in the italicized part of my question, I'm looking at $\mathbb{C}$ with the graphs of $+$ and $\times$, which are (ternary) relations rather than functions so every (nonempty) subset is the underlying set of a substructure. See also cody's comment above.

In particular, while $\mathcal{X}$'s $+$-part is trivial, $\mathbb{C}$'s isn't and could conceivably add some information (although I don't see how).

Ah, I missed the italicised part, sorry! :) Is the answer clear when we just look at multiplication, though? I guess it should be (haven't the time to think about it unfortunately), but I think this is worth saying.
